# Visual studio does not recognize React files with .js extension

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, visual-studio

[image]I'm facing an issue that Visual Studio 2017 doesn't recognize React file with js(not jsx) extension. It highlights everything as a syntax error, which makes code completely unreadable and not possible to work with. It forces me to work in 2 different environments VS Code and VS(since there is nothing like Resharper for VS Code and basically in my subjective opinion VS is better to work with .Net). Is there any possible workaround? Probably extension for VS to work with React? Spent some time but couldn't find anything which would solve this

Comment: +1 Struggling with same, editing in VS code works great but Visual Studio messes it great time in syntax highlight, warning, error.

Comment: Please show us the smallest possible JS sample that illustrates the issue.